Error "Mkdir /loki/tsdb-shipper-active: read-only file system" with Loki Helm Chart in GKE cluster
I am trying to set up Helm chart Loki in the GCP cluster. How do I manage this error?
“mkdir /loki/tsdb-shipper-active: read-only file system
error initialising module: store”
values.yaml:
loki:
  auth_enabled: false

  commonConfig:
    ring:
      instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
    replication_factor: 1
    path_prefix: /loki

  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: ab7d14a0f02ac9ab-loki-logs-bucket
    type: gcs

  schemaConfig:
    configs:
      - from: 2024-07-22
        store: tsdb
        object_store: gcs
        schema: v13
        index:
          prefix: index_
          period: 24h

  storageConfig:
    tsdb_shipper:
      active_index_directory: /loki/index
      cache_location: /loki/index_cache
    gcs:
      bucket_name: ab7d14a0f02ac9ab-loki-logs-bucket

serviceAccount:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: "loki-sa@linear-reporter.iam.gserviceaccount.com"


Simple solution
  storageConfig:
tsdb_shipper:
  active_index_directory: var/loki/index
  cache_location: var/loki/index_cache
  cache_ttl: 24h


I solved the error by adding the following configuration to the backend and writers
write:
  extraVolumes:
  - name: tsdb
    emptyDir: {}
  extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: tsdb
    mountPath: /loki
backend:
  extraVolumes:
  - name: tsdb
    emptyDir: {}
  extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: tsdb
    mountPath: /loki


Working variant too

I had the same issue with loki3.0

"error running loki" err="mkdir /tsdb-users: read-only file
system\nerror initialising module:
store\ngithub.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).initModule\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:138\ngithub.com/grafana/dskit/modules.(*Manager).InitModuleServices\n\t/src/loki/vendor/github.com/grafana/dskit/modules/modules.go:108\ngithub.com/grafana/loki/v3/pkg/loki.(*Loki).Run\n\t/src/loki/pkg/loki/loki.go:453\nmain.main\n\t/src/loki/cmd/loki/main.go:122\nruntime.main\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:267\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650"

Added the following in my values:
ingester: 
extraVolumeMounts: 
    - name: tsdb
      mountPath: /data
  # -- Volumes to add to the ingester pods
  extraVolumes: 
    - name: tsdb
      emptyDir: {}

